# What tasks should I do when performing a model validation?

Tags: r, mixed-model, mathematical-statistics, validation

I have a mixed model built using Data A below, and now I want to validate the model using Data B. What should I do to actually "validate" the model?

```
model <- lme(Y~1+X1+X3, random=~1|School, method="ML", data=A)
```

I know how to use "predict(model,B) - B$Y" to get residuals, but what else should I also perform in this validation process?

(I will not apply the cross-validation technique since my data are hierarchical structured.)

Comment: What are the two sample sizes?  The method of data splitting to validate a model requires amazingly large sample sizes, as opposed to resampling (strong internal validation).  You can do clustered resampling, e.g., cluster bootstrap.

Comment: Here are some suggestions on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_model_validation and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_diagnostic